Chat on Adonis 6
I'm building chat app with vite + react and adonis6
I'm so lost with the Doc,
Some one ca help please?
i don't really want to use another package :')
thank you
This is my code on the react client side
 const { transmit ,api } = useApi();
  const subscription = transmit.subscription(`private`);
  subscription.create()
    // subscription.onMessage((data) => {
  //   console.log("Nouveau message privé:", data);
  // });
  
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })

const sendMessageToApi = () =>{
  api.post('/chat/private', { message:'Hello' })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}

  useEffect(() => {
    sendMessageToApi()
  }, []);

This is my code on Adonis server side
export default class MessagesController {
    public async sendMessage({ request }: HttpContext) {
        const {  message } = request.body()
        transmit.broadcast(`private`, { username: 'lanz' })
        return 'Message sent'
      }

}

